# Socket IO event emission

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to get a client to speak with a server and am unable to receive the events being emitted by the client.  The connection is being established as the server console.logs `connected to localhost:61201` whenever a client connects; but, there is no response from the clientEvents that are being emitted at intervals by the client.

server.js

```
const port = 61201;
const ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"

var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, ipAddress);
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected to localhost:61201');
    socket.on('clientEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('message from the client:', data);
        socket.emit('serverEvent', "thanks server! for sending '" + data + "'");
    });
});
```

client.js

```
const port = 61201;
const ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
const url = 'http://' + ipAddress + ':' + port;

var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io(url);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.on('serverEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('new message from the server:', data);
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('clientEvent', Math.random());
        console.log('message sent from the client');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: what version of `socket-io` and `socket.io-client` are you using?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande 1.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `socket` object that the `connect` event returns. Try this

```
socket.on('connect', (clientSocket) => {
    console.log('connected to localhost:61201');
    clientSocket.on('clientEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('message from the client:', data);
        clientSocket.emit('serverEvent', "thanks server! for sending '" + data + "'");
    });
});
```

Comment: the event should be `socket.on("connection", (clientSocket) => { ... });`

Comment: @Jer I think both work https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-connect